# how to download only errata - rpm's by yum

Tags: rhel, yum

by this example we can install the errata

```
yum update --advisory=RHBA-2016:0694
```

but is it possible just to download the errata to local folder?

we just want to download the rpm's , without to install them

as all know we can do it also from redhat site , but I want to use yum for download errata - is it possible

Comment: This should help: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10154